# URL with get vars returns a file

Tags: php, url

I was wondering if it's possible to take a url request from an external server, process, and then return to the requester a different url. (specifically a media file)

For example: www.example.com/index.php?var1=blue&var2=green

I'd like to be able to use that url to access a media file hosted on the example.com server. I don't have access to code on the requesting site, so my php site index.php will need to take that url request and process based on the get vars, and the correct media file will be presented to the external site.

Comment: err what do u have so far?

Comment: Do you mean a dynamic redirect?

Comment: You're probably looking for `mod_rewrite`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and examples >>> http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: You could also use an `.htaccess` redirect. https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/

Comment: @fred true, but how would you handle processing the parameters? if you're just passing them to the external site exactly as they came in, `mod_rewrite` is perfect for this, but if you need to manipulate the passed values and request certain urls based on them, php is a better bet

Comment: @sgroves **I agree with you on that (PHP).** As to the "how", that will be up to the OP to further his/her research. I only provided the links for the information I already know, and there are many answers here on SO that I've seen in the past related to the subject.

Comment: @sgroves I just thought of it after, using a `$_GET` as per `marteljn's` answer below. Let's just hope the OP doesn't output before headers are sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing a redirect using `header`:

```
if (isset($_GET["var1"]) && $_GET["var1"] === "blue"){    
  header('Location: YOUR_BLUE_CONDITION_URL');
}else if (isset($_GET["var2"]) && $_GET["var2"] === "green"){
  header('Location: YOUR_GREEN_CONDITION_URL');
}
```

As @Fred noted below, make sure you do not output anything prior to modifying the headers.

Comment: It's a good example yes, however I would suggest to include an added note to make sure that no output is sent before the headers. It's a common mistake. Output could be HTML and even a whitespace.

Comment: @Fred I added a reference to your comment and brief explanation.

Comment: Very good, and thanks for taking me up on my suggestion. I see this common mistake often asked on SO; I also went through that myself in the beginning.

Comment: I've used header() a million times and I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Perfect!